# How to animate cells and buttons throughout the app in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionviewcell, rx-swift

I want to make click animations on every button and cell inside my app, basically all the views with actions. On every click I want a grayish blink.

The problem is the following: I made a custom class for button and the buttons across the app are working just fine. The problem is with cells as I try to make the animations rx-like. I have UITableView cells as well as UICollectionView cells and some views here and there, so I tried to do UIView extension which recognizes taps and if there is one - animation is played. I tried to do this with extension:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

extension UIView {
    func makeSelectionIndicatable(forInitialBackgroundColor color: UIColor) {
        let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
        tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        tapGesture.rx.event.bind(onNext: { [weak self] recognizer in
            if recognizer.state == .began {
                self?.backgroundColor = .global(color: .athens_gray)
            }
            if recognizer.state == .ended {
                self?.backgroundColor = color
            }
            if recognizer.state == .cancelled {
                self?.backgroundColor = color
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Obviously there is a dispose missing, but if I add one in extension - nothing will work. My question is: how to make animations rx-like, so that they'll be visible across app? Maybe I'm overthinking it and there are easier ways? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources)

```
data.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { index, model, cell in
  cell.textLabel?.text = model
}
```

> RxDataSources provides two special data source types that automatically take care of animating changes in the bound data source: RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource and RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource